# viewController does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource what is wrong with my code?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerviewdatasource

I have looked through many questions and answers and I cannot find the reason why my app keeps failing. Sorry for the inconvenience but can someone help me out? I am using swift 3.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //Distance
    @IBOutlet weak var setDistance: UIPickerView!

    var distance = ["1/2 Mile", "1 Mile", "2 Miles", "5 Miles"]

    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!


    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        print(location.altitude)
        print(location.speed)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Distance Stuff
        setDistance.delegate = self
        setDistance.dataSource = self

    }

        func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func setDistance(_ setDistance: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return distance.count
        }
        func setDistance(_ setDistance: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String {
            return distance[row]
        }


        //Map Stuff
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()








    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: check your code alignment //Map stuff.it is outside of braces, put it in viewdidload and build your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement delegate like below.the issues says that, you are including **UIPickerViewDataSource** but not implemented their **datasource**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class TestViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //Distance
    @IBOutlet weak var setDistance: UIPickerView!

    var distance = ["1/2 Mile", "1 Mile", "2 Miles", "5 Miles"]

    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!


    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        print(location.altitude)
        print(location.speed)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Distance Stuff
        setDistance.delegate = self
        setDistance.dataSource = self
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }

   /* func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func setDistance(_ setDistance: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return distance.count
    }
    func setDistance(_ setDistance: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String {
        return distance[row]
    }
 */
    func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       return distance.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
         return distance[row]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Xcode isn't able to implement or suggest the required functions the best way I found to identify them is to use the Documentation and API Reference.

You can show Quick help on the protocol (Option + Click) and then click on the Protocol Reference:

[image]

And this will open Documentation and API Reference which tells you more about Required functions:

[image]

You can also search for required key work (CMD + F) and type required in the search field.

Then you can implement them in your class:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataset.count
}
```

Xcode helps you find the related functions, for example, start typing `pickerview` and it will propose you the list of the protocol functions:

[image]

That's it.